# How to integrate pre-commit with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, pre-commit

I need to run pre-commit test on my project and so I downloaded the following extension for VSCode:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarkLarah.pre-commit-vscode

It says to simply "Type `pre-commit run` into the VSCode command bar", which give me:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Documents\VSCode\xxx> pre-commit run
pre-commit : The term 'pre-commit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pre-commit run
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pre-commit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Apparently I've missed a way to integrate this into my Powershell?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal window isn't the same thing as the visual studio command bar.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> will open the command palette.

Comment: Got it, thanks! So now when I try to run `pre-commit run` it in the command bar, I get a selection of tests from my project. No matter which one I try to run, I get "Could not find an installed version of pre-commit", even though the extension is installed.

Comment: That's a whole new kind of issue. And you may want to log it as an issue here: https://github.com/magicmark/pre-commit-vscode